# writing main() to call a function

Tags: ocaml

I have an OCaml function that converts a string to an array. What is the canonical way of writing a "main" function to call this and print the array.

```
let createArray pattern patArray  =
    (* some unimportant way of setting all the elements in the array patArray
       based on the string pattern *)


let main () =
    let pattern =  "Pattern" in
        let patArray = Array.create (String.length pattern) 0 in
            let res = createArray pattern patArray in
                Array.iter ~f:(printf "%d ") patArray;;  <------------------

main ()
```

1) In the above, if I leave out the ';;' , it does not work. What is the significance of that?

2) Instead of using a dummy binding "res" , can I somehow just write two statements to be executed sequentially , like so:

```
createArray pattern patArray
Array.iter ~f:(printf "%d ") patArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `;;`, the parser cannot know that the `main ()` call following that line is supposed to be a stand-alone expression (whitespace is not significant here).

You can use the following idiom instead:

```
let main () = ...
let () = main ()
```

The `let () = expr` idiom will evaluate an expression of type `unit` at that point. The initial `let` informs the parser that a new top-level `let` construct begins. Using `;;` is an alternative way to tell the parser about the end of a top-level construct, but is primarily intended for interactive use.

In order to evaluate two expressions sequentially, separate them with a semicolon (use parentheses or `begin ... end` if you're unsure about precedence rules). For example:

```
let patArray = Array.create (String.length pattern) 0 in
  createArray pattern patArray;
  Array.iter ~f:(printf "%d ") patArray
```

Or, using `begin` and `end` to make precedence clearer:

```
let patArray = Array.create (String.length pattern) 0 in begin
  createArray pattern patArray;
  Array.iter ~f:(printf "%d ") patArray
end
```

Without the `;`, the parser would not know whether `Array.iter` on the next line is supposed to an additional argument to the `createArray` call.